# Google app engine: sync all servers' time and clients' javascript timers

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine

I am developing a bidding system on Google App Engine with Python. A product is opened for bidding at a predefined time and the bidding lasts for 3 minutes. The price of the product drops down  every second by a constant value in the 3-minute period until it is zero. And the bidder who presses the "Bid" button first wins the bid. One critical issue in this application is that the time among all users should be perfectly synced so that everybody sees the same price at the same time. The following is what I have come up so far but it suffers from inaccurate timers.

When a user visit or refresh the page, the Python code will pass the sever time to the javascript timer and the timer starts to count down. The simplified javascript is as follows:

```
var count = {{timeToBid}};  // 'timeToBid' is in seconds and is inserted by the template engine
var price =={{initialPrice}}  // The initial product price
var currentPrice;             // Current price

function updateTime() {
  timeStr = ...;    // Set the time string to be HH:MM:SS
  $("#timeToBid").html(timeStr);   // Display time in the 'timeToBid' div
  if (count <= 180) {    // Start bidding
    currentPrice =  ...;  // Calculate the current price  
    $("#currentPrice").html(currentPrice);  // Update current price
  }
  count--;
  setTimeout(updateTime, 1000);  // Executed every second
}

updateTime();
```

The above javascript suffers significantly from unsynced timers among user browsers, as well as unsynced server times (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019514/keeping-track-of-time-with-1-second-accuracy-in-google-app-engine)). The current price displayed in each browser can vary in a huge range which makes the system totally unusable. This is a rather complicated problem and I am asking for good solutions. One or two seconds time inaccuracy is acceptable. My questions:

(a) To make the javascript timer more accurate, I plan to use AJAX to retrieve the server time every 10 seconds and then update 'count'. Is this a good solution? Or there are other options?

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/getServerTime",
   cache: false,
   success: function(serverCount) {
     count = parseInt(serverCount);
     return false;
   }
});
```

(b) I have absolutely no idea how to solve the server time inconsistency problem. Can anybody help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System clocks on App Engine servers are kept in sync: see [this authoritative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2591931/248432).

Every App Engine HTTP response has a `Date` header, like this `Date: Wed, 24 Apr 2013 06:03:37 GMT`. You can use this to sync browser with server time.

Comment: Really? Then the discussions in the link that I provided are wrong? Oh my, this is really a good news. I used to use Python's `datetime.datetime.now()` to get the server time, instead of `System.currentTimeMillis()`. Is it OK? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis()` is java. You should use whatever python provides. Also, instead of rolling your own try using `Date` header that exists in every request.

Comment: In any case you could use one backend instance, which would be a single point of uniform clock: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/